# what to add from custom jquery theme to asp.net project

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

Although I've used a little bit of jQuery UI before, I have never created my own custom them.
I now want to add this theme to my asp.net web forms project.

Within the zip folder there are 3 folders, CSS, JS and Development Bundle.  I know I need the CSS and JS, but not sure what I need to add from the development bundle.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The development bundle is included in case you want to make any changes to jQuery UI itself. In order to use it in your project, as you said you only need the CSS and JS.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I was really embarrassed asking the question.

Comment: @SheriTrager No problems, don't worry it's a perfectly valid question.